# Only portions of data are being written to a cvs file, rest is missing

Tags: python, csv, xml-parsing

I am parsing through many xml files and putting certain information into a csv file.  Because my xml files are named: "1.xml", "2.xml", etc... I am using a for loop to cycle through my different Xml file titles. However, based on the range that I use on my for loop, my csv file contains different data.  For example, when my for loop range is 1:200 my csv file includes info from my xml files 1 to 199.  However, when I change my range to 1:300, my csv file only contains info for my xml files 217 to 249.  The info actually stored on my csv file changes based on what I put in as my range for my for loop.  Has anyone else had this error and do you have any solutions?

My code is below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
from pathlib import Path

# open a file for writing

data_labels = open('DataLabels.csv', 'w', newline='')
missing_files = open('MissingFiles.csv', 'w', newline = '')

# create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(data_labels)
csvwriter2 = csv.writer(missing_files)
data_head = []
data = []
missingfiles = 0
missfiles = []

MediaId = "Media Id"
    #data_head.append (MediaId)

Family = "Family"
    #data_head.append (Family)

Species = "Species"
    #data_head.append (Species)

Genus = "Genus"
Content = "Content"
ClassId = "ClassId"
    #data_head.append (Genus)

data_head.append(MediaId)
    #   Family = member.find('Family').tag
data_head.append(Content)
data_head.append(ClassId)
data_head.append(Family)
    #   Species = member.find('Species').tag
data_head.append(Species)
    #   Genus = member.find('Genus').tag
data_head.append(Genus)

csvwriter.writerow(data_head)

for i in range (1, 190):
    #print (i)
    data = []

    inputfilename = str(i)+ ".xml"

    my_file = Path(inputfilename)
    if my_file.is_file():

        data_labels = open('DataLabels.csv', 'w', newline='')

        tree = ET.parse(inputfilename)
        root = tree.getroot()

        MediaId = root [2].text
        Content = root[4].text
        ClassId = root[5].text
        Family = root[6].text
        Species = root[7].text
        Genus = root[8].text

        #print (vote)
        #count = 0
        #for Image in root.find('MediaId'):
        #print (child.tag, child.attrib)
        #name = child.find('MediaId').text
    #   print (Image.find ('MediaId').text)
    ##csvwriter.writerow (data_head)

    #data = []

    #if count == 0:
    #   print ("count is zero i'm in loop")
    #   MediaId = member.find('MediaId').tag

    #   count = count + 1
    #else:
    #MediaId = root.findall('MediaId').text
        data.append(MediaId)
        data.append (Content)
        data.append (ClassId)
#Family = member.find('Family').text
        data.append(Family)
#Species = member.find('Species').text
        data.append(Species)
#Genus = member.find('Genus').text
        data.append(Genus)
        csvwriter.writerow(data)
        data_labels.close()
        #print (data)
    else:
        missingfiles = missingfiles +1
        missfiles = []
        missfiles.append(inputfilename)
        csvwriter2.writerow(missfiles)


print ("missing", missingfiles, "files")
data_labels.close()
missing_files.close()

print ("done")
```

Comment: Which operating system? I don't see how you get any data. That `data_labels = open('DataLabels.csv', 'w', newline='')` inside the `for` loop keeps overwriting the file. On linux, it will unlink the original file that you are writing data to. On windows, wouldn't this be a sharing violation? (I don't have a machine to test that one...).

Answer (score 0):

Open the csv in append mode ,else you are just overwriting the same file.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That did it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to divide your script in small readable functions.

First, you can create a function to parse a XML file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def parse_xml_file(xml_path):
    """ Parse an XML file and return the data. """
    # type: (str) -> list
    tree = ET.parse(xml_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    return [
        root[2].text,
        root[4].text,
        root[5].text,
        root[6].text,
        root[7].text,
        root[8].text]
```

This function parse a XML file and return one record containing a list of values.

Then, you can create a function to iterate a list of XML files (existing files) dans populate the CSV file:

```
import csv
import io
import os


def populate_data_labels(xml_path_list, work_dir="."):
    header = ["Media Id", "Family", "Species", "Genus", "Content", "ClassId"]
    with io.open(os.path.join(work_dir, 'DataLabels.csv'), 'w') as fd:
        writer = csv.writer(fd)
        writer.writerow(header)
        for xml_path in xml_path_list:
            writer.writerow(parse_xml_file(xml_path))
```

This function use `parse_xml_file()` to extract each record.

You can create a function to log the missing files. You can use CSV format (or a simple text file):

```
def populate_missing_files(missing_files, work_dir="."):
    header = ["Filename"]
    with io.open(os.path.join(work_dir, 'MissingFiles.csv'), 'w') as fd:
        writer = csv.writer(fd)
        writer.writerow(header)
        for xml_path in missing_files:
            writer.writerow([os.path.basename(xml_path)])
```

Finally, you can write a function which search the XML files and call the previous functions:

```
def parse_work_dir(work_dir="."):
    all_files = [os.path.join(work_dir, "{0}.xml".format(idx))
                 for idx in range(1, 190)]
    existing_files = (path for path in all_files if os.path.exists(path))
    populate_data_labels(existing_files, work_dir)
    missing_files = (path for path in all_files if not os.path.exists(path))
    populate_missing_files(missing_files, work_dir)
```

Usage:

```
parse_work_dir("/path/to/your/working/dir")
```

Comment: I think you are absolutely right and I should separate my code into smaller portions, but given my new-ness to coding it was easier to write it in pieces (I tested as I wrote the code) then to create and call functions.  Thank you so much for restructuring my code!